# Saved Outlook MailItem does not yet have EntryId

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

This is a weird one.

I have a saved Outlook MailItem (.msg file) opened from outside of Outlook, that for some reason does not yet have its EntryID set:

[image: OutlookSpy doesn't even know it]

Some context:

- This MailItem is a saved .msg file opened from Windows Explorer, not from Outlook.
- In my code, I originally start at the attachment and then get the MailItem as its parent.

If I inspect the MailItem while debugging, the EntryID is either null or an empty string...

[image: Empty EntryID during debugging]

... BUT if (for example) I expand `m_ObjectToDataMap` until I get to `_rcw` and expand *that* object's `Dynamic View` - that is when the EntryID gets set.

It's as if the MailItem isn't fully loaded yet, and some inspection of the values in the debugger somehow completes the initialization of the MailItem.

I have tried:

- Waiting a few seconds with `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep()`.
- `parent.Save()` even though I know this is not a new MailItem being composed.
- refreshing the active inspector.
- attempting to get the MailItem via other methods instead of getting it off the attachment.

None of these fix the problem. Why does this happen? How would I fix or get around this issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standalone MSG files do not have entry ids. This is to be expected.

Comment: Would the absence of an EntryId on a MailItem be an accurate test of whether it is standalone or not? I will need to account for this in my code, so being able to determine if the MailItem was opened from outside of Outlook would be quite valuable.

Comment: No, it can also be because the message is not yet saved.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm here to learn. What would be the recommended way to determine if a MailItem was opened from outside of Outlook?

Comment: None. When an MSG file is opened, Outlook creates a temporary copy in one of its folders. The MSG file is not directly displayed.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, I ended up not relying on the MailItem in order to achieve my goal.